# React Native lost control of iOS status bar after calling 3-party library

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I am using a 3rd-party library it will hide iOS status bar when calling. After that, I can't show the status bar back on screen.

I can control status bar by `StatusBar` component in React Native normally.

However, I tried to call a iOS library https://www.dynamsoft.com/Products/dynamsoft-webcam-sdk.aspx it will hide the status bar when showing it's screen. 
After it hide the status bar, I can't show it up again using `StatusBar.setHidden(false)`.

It don't prompt any error, just simply no effect.

Anyone knows what's going on and how can I show the status bar back in this situation?

Comment: Please make sure StatusBar.setHidden(false) will executing after completely dismiss the calling screen. If you are executing StatusBar.setHidden(false) before or in between of dismissal of calling screen, then no effect.

Comment: I am sure StatusBar.setHidden(false) is executed after that library screen completely dismissed. I added a button on the screen and press manually after library screen dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following code in your screen where you want to show your status bar

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native';

class MyComponent extends Component {

componentDidMount() {
   StatusBar.setHidden(false);
}
}
```

or you can also do

```
<StatusBar hidden={false} />
```

This will help you to show status bar in your desired screen

Comment: As said in my question, StatusBar.setHidden(false) has no effect

Answer (score 0):

The workaround below may work.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native';

class MyComponent extends Component {

componentDidMount() {
   setTimeout(() => {StatusBar.setHidden(false);},1000)
}
}
```